# Is HDD IO-operation perform when called a method from referenced .dll?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dll, reference

My .NET application uses third-party .dlls (HtmlAgilityPack.dll - HTML Parser, SgmlReaderDll.dll - HTML->XML converter). After I've ported app to Windows Azure virtual machine, which has better characteristics than my local PC, methods from referenced dlls became work much slowly. Framework's methods work faster. So maybe HDD IO-operation perform each time I call referenced .dll method? I can't guess another reason.

Comment: Without code that could help us answer the question, this doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: Any code from referenced dlls works slowly. It happens, because app reads .dll from hard drive each time this .dll's method or class etc. called. So referenced methods itself work faster as expected, but calling them from VM's HDD each time are slow. Azure VM Disk IO-operations are slowly then on local PC. That's the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at Perfmon stats on either machine to see bottlenecks or install tools like those from Sysinternals to see exactly which file handles are open on the machine.  From my experience, Azure Disk IO was slower than my local machine so did end up using more in-memory processing.